# Find the limit of the following power series - What do they mean by that?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, power-series

The title speaks for itself. This is a question from a complex analysis exam. A student asked the teacher what they mean when they ask for the limit of the power series:

$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}(-2)^n\frac{z^n}{n+1}$$

I'm not a student in that course and I'm only guessing. Do they mean the sum of the power series? I'm just brushing up on complex analysis and I'm sure I'll find the relevant method but I'd like to know what I'm looking for first.

Comment: I'd not ask for the *limit*, but for the *sum*. Maybe the teacher used the former term, though not common in this context.

Comment: Because the phrase "limit of the power series" is not generally used terminology, if this was actually the exact wording used by the teacher, then the teacher's response is rather arrogant in my opinion, and brings to mind the phrase about [not throwing stones in glass houses](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/people-who-live-in-glass-houses-shouldn-t-throw-stones) and [the Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect). The phase could mean find a closed form for the sum, determine the convergence disk, or possibly something else.

Comment: The correct terminology, IMO, should be “limit of a series” and “sum of the sequence”. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics): Series itself IMPLIES addition. A SEQUENCE is an array of objects, while their SUM is a series. So “sum of a series” is just like saying “using your voice while singing”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the nomenclature is that the sum of the series is a limit. Namely, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^N a_n.$$ Therefore I'm sure the teacher wanted this limit (hence the sum) to be calculated. To defend the use of the word limit in this context I'd like to remind that we verify if the sequence is *convergent* or not. If there's a convergence, then we can ask for a limit.

Of course we could consider anoter limit, like
$$\lim_{z\to R}\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_n \cdot z^n,$$ where $R$ is a radius of convergence, but I don't think here's the case.